# Xamarin binding, Label only displaying 1 character

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding

I have a Label that is binding to a property, so that when that property is updated, the Label is updated.  But, for example, if the property has the value 500, the label only displays "5", instead of "500".  If I remove the binding and hard code label = "500", the entire string show up.  What's the deal?  My code looks something like this ...

```
var myLabel = new Label
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    FontSize = 30,
    TextColor = Color.Red
};

myLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("SomeProperty", source:this);

// where SomeProperty is a property that gets an integer value dynamically
```

so, running code similar to that, the label is output as "5" (assuming SomeProperty = 500, if SomeProperty is 432354, the label shows only "4").  However, if instead of setting the binding I do

```
myLabel = "500";
```

then, the label shows "500".

Why is the binding cutting off the string???

Comment: you need to specify a WidthRequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its is not the *binding cutting off your string*, it is size of `Label` not changing dynamically for your content. Set it directly by setting `WidthRequest` or `MinimumWidthRequest` properties

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that.  That was it.  Thank you very much.